# ImageField upload_to not working

Tags: django, file, upload

Hay guys, I'm using an ImageField to upload files, however when i add upload_to to the ImageField it doesnt append the directory to the MEDIA_ROOT

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/username/Django/site/assests/'

picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads')
```

i get an error saying

```
No such file or directory: u'/Users/username/Django/site/assests/2homemap.png'
```

Also the record added to the DB is just the file name (without the uploads)

any ideas?

Comment: which version of django are you running?

Comment: turns out an old version, seems to work now after updating to the latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure the MEDIA_ROOT directory exists
2. Check your permissions, make sure the user under which the django is running can write to the target directory (MEDIA_ROOT + 'uploads')

Comment: Issue was i was using an old version of django!

Comment: what version do you use now then?